# How can I make type environments for an expression to satisfy specific conditions?

Tags: types, ocaml, environment, typechecking, open-closed-principle

I have a question to make the environment of `if true then x else y` not closed, closed but not well typed, and closed and well typed. How can I do this in OCaml?

All I know is that not closed means that there is a variable that is not bound. So x and y will not be bound in this case. Additionally, well typed means that the expression satisfies the grammar.

Im not sure how to apply that here however and I only have very wrong answers. Maybe something like:

```
if (x:int, y:int) then (true) else (false)

if (x:int, y: int) then (x: bool) else (y: bool)

if (true) then (x: int) else (y: int)
```

for the 3 conditional respectively

Answer (score 0):

You're asking us to do your homework, but we're not taking the class! So we don't have much to go on.

The basic way to bind a variable in OCaml is with `let`. So if you don't have `let x = ...` then `x` is unbound (other things being equal). If you do have something like `let x = 4 in ...` then `x` is bound.

**Update**

Note that `(x : int)` does not bind `x`, i.e., it doesn't associate it with a value. It just specifies (or ascribes) the type of `x`.

Comment: Yes I understadn that but im not sure how to apply that to the case of conditionals. THere is no "let" in an if statement no?

Comment: `let ... in ...` can be used within a conditional expression: `if x then let y = ... in ... else ...` However, the name is _locally_ bound in that case.

Comment: The environment is (in essence) outside the expression. Hence the name "environment". So you can have `let` *outside* the `if` that causes `x` and `y` to be bound or not.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like maybe you're coming at this from a Python-esque dynamic viewpoint:

```py
>>> if True:
...   y = 42
... else:
...   x = 27
... 
>>> y
42
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>>
```

OCaml is a statically typed language, where the types of variables are known at compile time. Both `x` and `y` have to be bound before you can use them or your program will not compile, much less *run*. If you need to conditionally bind values to them, you might have a conditional expression return a tuple of values, and use pattern-matching in a let binding:

```ml
utop # let (x, y) = if true then (1, 2) else (6, 7);;
val x : int = 1
val y : int = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's *E* be your expression `if true then x else y`.

You can change the environment of *E* by adding bindings around it:

```
let x = 0 in E
```

In which case `x` is bound in *E* but `y` is unbound.

I think the solution you are asked to provide is no more complex than that. The same applies to the other parts of your question.